# Count Number of Visits per Day

Tags: excel, count, pivot

I am currently "developing" an excel template where a i need to registrer (count) the number of visits performed by someone per day of a month.
The template is like this:

The column AGENT ID and DAY OF THE MONTH has to be fixed, wheter it includes data or not.

In order to feed the template i would like to paste the source of the data in another tab, as it follows:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9nHL.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oeTS.png

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a table like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| A1 (1/1/2021) | 2 |
| A1 (2/1/2021) | 1 |
| A1 (3/1/2021) | 0 |

If so, here is the formula:

```
=LET(
    Column_Key, Table1[DATE OF THE VISIT],
    Column_Filter1, Table1[AGENT ID],
    List_Filter1, "A1",

    Categories, SORT(UNIQUE(Column_Key)),
    Categories_Names, List_Filter1 & " (" & TEXT(Categories, "M/D/YYYY") & ")",
    Array_BoolKey, (TRANSPOSE(Column_Key)=Categories)+0,
    Mask1, TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Column_Filter1,List_Filter1))),

    Array_BoolMasked, Array_BoolKey*Mask1,
    Array_Ones, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Array_BoolMasked),1,1,0),

    Body_Count_Visits, MMULT(Array_BoolMasked, Array_Ones),

    Array_Seq, {1,2},
    Array_Body, CHOOSE(Array_Seq, Categories_Names, Body_Count_Visits),

    Return, Array_Body,
    Array_Body
)
```

The formula creates an array `Array_BoolKey` that is `Categories` tall by `AGENT ID` wide. It will show `TRUE` if `AGENT ID` visited on the specific `Categories`.

`Mask1` creates an array 1 tall by `AGENT ID` wide. It shows `TRUE` if `AGENT ID` =
`List_Filter1`. `List_Filter1` can be a list if required. For instance, if you want to know if `A1` and `A2` visited, use `List_Filter1, {"A1", "A2"}`.

Multiplying `Array_BoolKey` by `Mask1` to get `Array_BoolMasked` sets all agents not in `List_Filter1` to `FALSE`.

The last step is summing across each row of `Array_BoolMasked` to get `Body_Count_Visits`. `Body_Count_Visits` is `Categories` tall by 1 wide. To sum across an array, you need to use `MMULT`.

To output correctly, we need to combine the `Categories_Names` and `Body_Count_Visits` arrays. We do that with `CHOOSE`.

If you want to add headers and footers to the table, this formula adds them:

```
=LET(
    Column_Key, Table1[DATE OF THE VISIT],
    Column_Filter1, Table1[AGENT ID],
    List_Filter1, "A1",

    Categories, SORT(UNIQUE(Column_Key)),
    Categories_Names, List_Filter1 & " (" & TEXT(Categories, "M/D/YYYY") & ")",
    Array_BoolKey, (TRANSPOSE(Column_Key)=Categories)+0,
    Mask1, TRANSPOSE(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Column_Filter1,List_Filter1))),

    Array_BoolMasked, Array_BoolKey*Mask1,
    Array_Ones, SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(Array_BoolMasked),1,1,0),

    Body_Count_Visits, MMULT(Array_BoolMasked, Array_Ones),

    Total_Count_Visits, IFERROR(SUM(Body_Count_Visits),"-"),

    Array_Seq, {1,2},
    Array_Header, CHOOSE( Array_Seq,  "Date",                          "Agent" ),
    Array_Body,     CHOOSE( Array_Seq,  Categories_Names,  Body_Count_Visits ),
    Array_Total,     CHOOSE( Array_Seq,  "Total",                          Total_Count_Visits ),

    Range1,Array_Header,
    Range2,Array_Body,
    Range3,Array_Total,
    Rows1,ROWS(Range1), Rows2,ROWS(Range2), Rows3,ROWS(Range3), Cols1,COLUMNS(Range1),
    RowIndex, SEQUENCE(Rows1 + Rows2 + Rows3), ColIndex,SEQUENCE(1, Cols1),
    RangeTable,IF(
        RowIndex<=Rows1,
        INDEX(Range1,RowIndex,ColIndex),
        IF(RowIndex<=Rows1+Rows2,
            INDEX(Range2,RowIndex-Rows1,ColIndex),
            INDEX(Range3,RowIndex-Rows1-Rows2,ColIndex)
    )),

    Return, RangeTable,
    Return
)
```

The output table looks like this:

| Date | Agent |
| --- | --- |
| A1 (1/1/2021) | 2 |
| A1 (2/1/2021) | 1 |
| A1 (3/1/2021) | 0 |
| Total | 3 |

For reference, here is the input data in table format:

| AGENT ID | DATE OF THE VISIT |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 1/1/2021 |
| A1 | 1/1/2021 |
| A1 | 2/1/2021 |
| A2 | 1/1/2021 |
| A2 | 1/1/2021 |
| A2 | 1/1/2021 |
| A5 | 2/1/2021 |
| A6 | 3/1/2021 |
| A7 | 3/1/2021 |
| A7 | 2/1/2021 |
| A9 | 3/1/2021 |
| A9 | 3/1/2021 |
| A11 | 3/1/2021 |